# Batch Extract by Mask, but customize individual output names

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, batch, error-000865

I want to extract by mask (the same mask everytime) on about 500 raster's, but I want to just append the name of every input raster.  So if a raster is titled Landsat_010182 I just want to add _clip to it so that I still know what every image contains.  Is this something I would need to do in python or is there another way to do this?

Edit:

This is the exact code I am trying:

```
import arcpy
import glob
import os

arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

"""folder containing only input rasters and nothing else"""
indir = r'D:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\Practice_bands'

"""absolute path to mask layer"""
mask = r'D:\Sheyenne\sheyenne_area_poly.shp'

"""create emply list to hold paths to input rasters"""
inrasters = []

"""populate the list inrasters with all paths to .tif in directory"""
os.chdir(indir)
for r in glob.glob('*.tif'):
    inrasters.append(r)
#
#"""iterate over all input .tif from list inrasters"""
for inraster in inrasters:
#
#    """create a unique name for each output raster"""
    outraster = inraster.replace('.tif','_clip.tif')

#    """Clip each raster with it's unique name as output""    
    arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(inraster,mask)
```

but it returns the error:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000865: Input raster: LT50290282011268PAC01_sr_band1.tif does not exist.
Failed to execute (ExtractByMask).
```

LT50290282011268PAC01_sr_band1.tif is the first file in the `inrasters` list

Edit:

Everything works as I expect up until the loop starts.  When I print `inrasters` all of them are listed.  When I print `outraster` only the second raster in my list is printed.  So somewhere in the loop is when things are breaking down.  Also, I never actually use the variable `outraster` which may be part of the problem.

Edit:

I got it to work using this code:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace='D:\Sheyenne\Practice_bands'
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

"""absolute path to your mask layer"""
mask = r'D:\Sheyenne\sheyenne_area_poly.shp'

"""Loop through rasters, append names and savefiles"""
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
for raster in rasters:
     outraster = raster.replace('.tif','_clip.tif')
     arcpy.gp.ExtractByMask_sa(raster,mask,outraster)
```

Comment: for what its worth I ended up just using a python code to rename the new output files based on the file names of the old input names

Comment: inraster (variable) not 'inrasters' (string) on offending line

Comment: actually that was a typo, I changed it above but the same error is still returned

Comment: You still have `'inraster'` (a string) instead of `inraster` (a variable name that you are creating when iterating your `inrasters` list).  The error looks like it may be out of sync with your posted code.  Something you may want to think about is that the code you are using is very un-ArcPythonic.  I would be using `arcpy.da.Walk`  (and/or perhaps `arcpy.ListRasters`) rather than `glob` to do something like this.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I modified my post and will look into using `arcpy.ListRasters`.  Thank you.

Comment: I think you should insert some `print` statements into your code to ensure that your variables are set to what you think they are.

Comment: `arcpy.ListRasters` was very helpful, I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the field from the batch generator and paste it into excel to make custom output names if you don't use python. Can then be copied back into batch from excel.

I'd highly recommend using this as an opportunity to try Python, this a perfect beginners application. Something like this should do the trick:

```
import glob
import os

"""folder containing only your input rasters and nothing else"""
indir = 'c:/GIS/input_rasters/'

"""absolute path to your mask layer"""
mask = 'c:/GIS/clip_mask.shp'

"""create emply list to hold paths to input rasters"""
inrasters = []

"""populate the list inrasters with all paths to .tif in directory"""
os.chdir(indir)
for r in glob.glob('*.tif'):
    inrasters.append(r)

"""iterate over all input .tif from list inrasters"""
for inraster in inrasters:

    """create a unique name for each output raster"""
    outraster = inraster.replace('.tif','_clip.tif')

    """Clip each raster with it's unique name as output"""
    r = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(inraster,mask)
    r.save(outraster)
```

Comment: I will definitely try it in python, didn't realize you could copy and paste and make changes so simple!  I need to learn python anyways though....

Comment: when I try to run this in python it says that for extract by mask only 2 arguments are taken and three are given.  When i take out `'outraster'` it says that the tool is not licensed even though I have successfully used it within ArcMap itself.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the script, try now. If you are running within the Python window of ArcGIS, and you have everything checked when you go to 'customize->extensions,' there's no reason this shouldn't run. In you are running in Python outside of ArcGIS, you'll need to import arcpy first in the first line of the script.

Comment: yea im pretty sure the code is good, im just having problems with arcpy and licensing I'll have to work out.  Thanks again!

Comment: I solved my acrpy problem, when I run this code it returns: `ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000865: Input raster: inrasters does not exist.
ERROR 000865: Input raster or feature mask data: mask does not exist.
Failed to execute (ExtractByMask)`  When I print inrasters though they are all there

Comment: I had them as strings rather than variable names. My bad...fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to loop through the list of rasters generated from `glob.glob()` and append them to a new list. I would take the following approach:

1. Define the input and output workspaces
2. List all rasters using `glob`
3. Loop through the list
4. Define the output name and path
5. Perform extract by mask
6. Save the extract by mask

---

```
import arcpy, glob, os

arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')

# folder containing only input rasters and nothing else
inws = r'D:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\Practice_bands'
outws = r'D:\Sheyenne\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\Practice_bands\out' # Note the new output workspace folder

# absolute path to mask layer
mask = r'D:\Sheyenne\sheyenne_area_poly.shp'

# Generate a list of all .tif files (Note this lists full paths)
rasters = glob.glob(os.path.join(inws, "*.tif"))

# iterate over all input .tif from raster list
for ras in rasters:

    # Define the output path and name
    outname = os.path.join(outws, os.path.basename(ras).split(".")[0] + "_clp.tif")

    # Perform the EBM
    out_extract = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(ras, mask)

    # Save the output
    out_extract.save(outname)
```